# How do I install the "Birthday by Month" extension in CiviCRM 4.7.31

Tags: extension

I am a newbie and here's my first question - how do I install the Birthday by Month extension in my CiviCRM? It is not showing up in my list of available extensions. I am on CiviCRM 4.7.31

Answer (score 1):

So that means it's not officially tagged as compatible with 4.7.x - and/or not reviewed (requirement for automated distribution);

Answer (score 0):

Birthday by Month extension has not been updated to work with latest CiviCRM versions and if you [look at the source code here](https://bitbucket.org/clearriver/org.namelessnetwork.birthdaysbymonth/src/27c065b220af4bec83bf4e0b6c03b7dcdf83ea58/info.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), it's only compatible with 4.2.

On a general note, extensions can be installed via CiviCRM Manage Extensions page, but that list is limited to native (CMS-independent) extensions and subjected to reviews. However, you can manually install an extension by copying the source files to the respective extensions directory (dependent on your directory settings).

Please refer CiviCRM documentations for further information https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/

Comment: Just to clarify - when an extension is noted as compatible with a version, it does not mean that it won't work with other versions just that it has not been verified to work with other versions.  So if it is of interest to you, try it (on a test server) and see whether it works.  That said, a lot has changed since 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extension that will list birthdays in 4.7 then 'Systopia birthdays' works.  It can be found [here](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.birthdays)  I've used it in 4.7.30 so it should be OK

Comment: I installed the extension in CiviCRM 5.2.2 just recently and ran it to capture all the contacts with birthdays falling in August. Yesterday, it showed folks with birthdays ranging from 2/8/2018 to 31/8/2018. It missed those people with birthday on 1/8/2018.  When I ran the same report today, it only showed people with birthdays from 5/8/2018- 31/8/2018.

I checked for September and it is showing results for all the days from 1/9/2018 to 30/9/2018, though I

Are you aware of any bugs that could be causing this? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: This is what I was told by Systopia: Hi Raja

I think there is simply a misunderstanding of the concept here. The
extension is supposed to show the _upcoming_ birthdays, so it never
looks into the past. The idea is that you can have a report (and/or
dashlet) to show you any upcoming birthdays.

Does that answer your question?

Cheers
Björn